# QEMU stop/continue memory releasing

Tags: qemu

When using qemu-monitor console, i do PAUSE / CONTINUE of different VMs with stop/cont commands, which works ok, and my main CPU usage stays low.

Is it possible to keep memory usage low this or similar way???

Because every VM tooks fixed size of RAM (in my case 2GB option '-m 2048')... and 'stop' do not release it.

Comment: I assume you've ruled out simply stopping the VM.  That given, why do you care?  Make sure you've got enough swap space available, and the core footprint will get swapped out to HDD as soon as something else needs the memory.

Comment: @MadHatter ... hm, it seems logical, but when my main (host) machine shows 95% memory is used, everything seems unstable to me. Maybe qemu have some option to explicitly do that (save guest mem to disk and free it on stop or similar command)

Comment: If you actually stop the VM, the memory should be released; if you only suspend it, the pages remain in use, though (swap space permitting) they'll be swapped out as time passes, as I said.  Do not infer anything from the fact that your RAM is 95% in use, this is normal for Linux.  See many questions on SF, or http://www.linuxatemyram.com/, for more details.